# Extract upper and lower triangular with different value part of a NumPy matrix to a 2 column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a `test_matrix`:

```
    A  B  C
A  nan 10 20
B  30 nan 40
C  50 60 nan
```

My DataFrame should be:

```
cus1    cus2    lower    upper
 A       B       30       10
 A       C       50       20
 B       C       60       40
```

I can extract DataFrame above with 2 parts (I extract the upper is first and the lower triangular is second):

```
lower_triangular = test_matrix[np.tril_indices(test_matrix.shape[0], -1)]
upper_triangular = test_matrix[np.triu_indices(test_matrix.shape[0], 1)]
```

But when I create a DataFrame, I have a bunch of code is very complex to extract right DataFrame above.

Can I extract it one times?

**UPDATE SOLUTION**

*Mr/Ms Pygirl* give a good solution, but when your matrix has value `0`:

```
    A   B   C
A  nan 10   0
B  30  nan  40
C  0   60  nan
```

Pygirl-solution will give a result:

```
cus1    cus2    lower    upper
A       B       30       10
B       C       60       40
```

If you want to get a value `0` (index: `AC` and `CA`), you should use:

```
df2=df.where(np.triu(np.ones(df.shape)).astype(np.bool)).stack().rename_axis(('cus1', 'cus2')).reset_index(name='upper')

y=df.where(np.tril(np.ones(df.shape)).astype(np.bool)).stack().values
```

The result:

```
cus1    cus2    lower    upper
A       B       30       10
A       C       0        0
B       C       60       40
```

**PROBLEM 2 (AFTER USE PYGIRL-SOLUTION)**

I have a `test_matrix` with 4x4 dimension:

```
    A    B    C    D
A  nan   10   20   30 
B  40    nan  50   60
C  70    80   nan  90
D  100   110  120  nan
```

My DataFrame should be:

```
cus1    cus2    lower    upper
 A       B       40       10
 A       C       70       20
 A       D       100      30
 B       C       80       50
 B       D       110      60
 D       C       120      90
```

But I get a wrong result (lost DC and wrong AD,BC):

```
cus1    cus2    lower    upper
 A       B       40       10
 A       C       70       20
 A       D       *80*     *30*
 B       C       *100*    *50*
 B       D       110      60
```

Comment: Can you show your solution? I assume you already used `np.triu` and `np.tril`.

Comment: hi @MichaelSzczesny, I updated the code. Sure

Comment: Can you also provide the code you are using to create the `test_matrix`?

Comment: hi @srishtigarg, this is my code `a = np.array([[np.nan,10,20],[30,np.nan,40],[50,60,np.nan]])`

Comment: I am glad you figured it out :) at that time I didn't get what you actually wanted sorry I could not help then.

Comment: You helped me very much,@Pygirl. Your solution makes me more knowledgeable. Thank you so much. <3

Comment: @ToanNguyenPhuoc: It is solved now :) I didn't add the merging by keys step. I thought it will work If I do basic concatenation. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
li = ['A', 'B' , 'C']
df = pd.DataFrame(test_matrix, index=li, columns=li)
    
df2=df.where(np.triu(df).astype(np.bool)).stack().rename_axis(('cus1', 'cus2')).reset_index(name='upper')
y=df.where(np.tril(df).astype(np.bool)).stack().values#.reset_index(name='upper')
df2['lower'] = y
```

---

**df2:**

```
    cus1    cus2    upper   lower
0   A       B       10.0    30.0
1   A       C       20.0    50.0
2   B       C       40.0    60.0
```

---

### EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(test_matrix, index=li, columns=li)
    
df2=df.where(np.triu(df).astype(np.bool)).stack().rename_axis(('cus1', 'cus2')).reset_index(name='upper')
df1=df.where(np.tril(df).astype(np.bool)).stack().rename_axis(('cus2', 'cus1')).reset_index(name='lower')
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['cus2', 'cus1'])
```

**df3:**

```
  cus2 cus1 lower   upper
0   B   A   40.0    10.0
1   C   A   70.0    20.0
2   C   B   80.0    50.0
3   D   A   100.0   30.0
4   D   B   110.0   60.0
5   D   C   120.0   90.0
```

---

Comment: Thank you so much, but can I ask you a question? Why we need `astype(np.bool)`.

Comment: df.where --> Replace values where the condition is False.

Comment: `df.where` will set value `0` and `nAn` is False, can I keep value `0`?

Comment: When you will stack you will see the difference. Try to run the code partwise.

Comment: Since I need to take above diagonal values I will make rest of the thing as nan  but using `df.where` my diagonal value will also be there but luckily they all are Nan(originally) So I don't have to convert them into nan before doing stack. Hope you got my point

Comment: hi @Pygirl, sorry to ask you again, if my matrix has dimension n x n (4x4,5x5,...), your solution gives a wrong result. Did you have any solution to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide sample array? I will look into that.

Comment: simple array: `test_matrix = np.array([[np.nan,10,20,30],[40,np.nan,50,60],[70,80,np.nan,90],[100,110,120,np.nan]])`

Comment: It works how it is not working for you? how is it wrong? Can you edit your post? so that I can see the problem. It won't work for matrix other than square one. It's working fine for me. :)

Comment: I updated my post. I applied your solution and get the wrong results with AD and BC and lost data DC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226594/discussion-between-pygirl-and-toan-nguyen-phuoc).

Answer (score 1):

Code Setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test_matrix = np.array([[np.nan,10,20],[30,np.nan,40],[50,60,np.nan]])

lower_triangular = test_matrix[np.tril_indices(test_matrix.shape[0], -1)]

lower_triangular = list(np.tril(test_matrix).flat)
upper_triangular = list(np.triu(test_matrix).flat)

lower_triangular = [x for x in lower_triangular if x>0]
upper_triangular = [x for x in upper_triangular if x>0]


cus1 = np.tril_indices(test_matrix.shape[0], -1)[0]
cus2 = np.tril_indices(test_matrix.shape[0], -1)[1]

q = pd.DataFrame(
    {'cus1': cus1,
     'cus2': cus2,
     'lower': lower_triangular,
     'upper': upper_triangular
    })
```

Output:

```
   cus1  cus2  lower  upper
0     1     0   30.0   10.0
1     2     0   50.0   20.0
2     2     1   60.0   40.0
```